# Why am I indignant?

Tags: frog-fractions

I am a frog eating fruit. My score is a complex fraction and sometimes my indignity rises. What causes my indignity? Can I be less indignant?

Comment: A Frog Fractions question? Wild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This guide says to "get good"

> Don’t let the bugs get on the apples, otherwise your “indignity” increases and you can lose the round.

https://www.nayuki.io/page/frog-fractions-guide#1-frog-fractions-missile-defense-dvorak-touhou